# Get the UIEdgeInsets from subtracting 2 CGRects

Tags: geometry, cgrect, cgrectmake, uiedgeinsets

I have a `CGRect` "A" contained in another `CGRect` "B"

I'm not sure on how `UIEdgeInsets` are calculated - and I keep getting the arithmatic wrong -  what I need is the edge insets (= "EI") such that "A" will be equal to "B" after performing:

```
UIEdgeInsetsRect("A","EI") == "B"
```

Is there a macro such that

```
"EI" = UIEdgeInsetsFromRects("B","A") ?
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197662/294884